# Displaying attribute tables with merged cells in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, table, layouts

I am new to ArcGIS Desktop 10.1. I would like to display a table providing information about the Region, Province and district in the layout view of ArcMap.

For example, this is my attribute table:

[image]

I want to display the following table in the layout view of ArcMap:
[image]

Comment: Export to Excel or DBF and create a pivot table or merge cells in Microsoft Excel (or similar program) then insert into the layout... there's only so much you can do from ArcMap, no matter how powerful ArcMap a GIS package not a spreadsheet program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @MichaelStimson, if you are not skilled in ArcPy then you could:

> Export to Excel or DBF and create a pivot table or merge cells in
>   Microsoft Excel (or similar program) then insert into the layout.

With ArcPy other options open up to you like creating the "table" from graphic and text elements, or from feature classes, but they all take a reasonable amount of coding.